# comparing one column in two spreadsheets in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am making an excel comparing program but I seem to be stuck. I want to compare two excel files in a spreadsheet. Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Users\\Bill\\Desktop\\CK_Server_list_0.1.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

wb1 = 
openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Users\\Bill\\Desktop\\CK_Server_list_0.2.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active

for x in ws.iter_cols(max_col=1):
        for cell in x:
                print(cell.value, cell.coordinate)


for row1 in ws1.iter_cols(min_col=1):
        if row1[0].value != ws.cell(row=x, column=1).value:
                print(str(row1[0].value) + ' is not equal to ' + str(ws.cell(row=x, column=1).value + ' ' + str(ws.cell(row=x, column=1).coordinate)))
```

And every time I run this it gives me an error saying that `tuple() < int()`. Can anyone fix this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you attempting to compare a column from the first table (0.1.xlsx) to a row in the second (0.2.xlsx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error pops up because your variable `x` contains a `tuple` of `cell` objects at the time when the line `if row1[0].value != ws.cell(row=x, column=1).value:` gets executed. The input argument `row` requires an `int` value instead.

I think that a good approach for your problem would be to use `for` loops in combination with `zip` statements (more on `zip` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1663826/7306999)):

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Users\\Bill\\Desktop\\CK_Server_list_0.1.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Users\\Bill\\Desktop\\CK_Server_list_0.2.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active

for (col, col_1) in zip(ws.iter_cols(), ws1.iter_cols()):
    for (cell, cell_1) in zip(col, col_1):
       if cell.value != cell_1.value:
           print(str(cell.value) + ' is not equal to ' + str(cell_1.value) + ' ' + str(cell.coordinate))
```

Comment: what if size of rows and columns is not same?

Comment: @bhushanpardhi The `zip` statement stops once the smallest input iterable is exhausted. Therefore this code will only compare the rows and columns that are present in both excel sheets.